# How can I select/activate a unit behind another unit?

Tags: civilization-5

I have two sleeping units standing behind another unit each on the same field. I try to click on their shields but Civ 5 always focuses on the unit in front of it. How can I select a unit behind another unit? (In both cases it's a civilian unit behind a military unit.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out double-clicking on the units' field sometimes does the trick.

Comment: Ten more hours to go.

Answer (score 3):

Usually when you have two units stacked on a tile, you can pick the one behind it by clicking on the icons.  Civilian units generally have triangular icons, while military units have circle or shield-shaped (if they're fortified) icons.  You can also generally click the tile repeatedly to cycle through the units on that tile, if you so desire.

In certain cases, such as when a unit is activated during the "complete automated tasks" portion of a turn, you won't be able to select just any unit - usually, trying to select another unit will cause the selection to jump back to the previously selected unit.  You'll end up in this situation if you gave a long move order to a unit and they can no longer complete it, for example.

Comment: No, first trick didn't work at all. Whenever I clicked on the shield of the unit behind the top unit, the top unit would activate. But clicking repeatedly (i.e. double-clicking) did help.

Answer (score 2):

First method: You need to click above the shield (not on it). Move the cursor so that it's a few pixels above the shield in the back. You'll see the behind shield get the pulsing glow. It may also throw up a tool tip that tells you to click to select that unit.

Second method: Go into the Military Overview (<kbd>F3</kbd>) and click on the unit. When you close the overview window, that unit will be selected. (Actually, it gets selected while you're still in the overview. The main screen gets dimmed behind that window but you can still see the unit being selected in the bottom left corner.)

Comment: The first doesn't always work. The second is a good tip.

Answer (score 0):

I can't check at the moment, but I am pretty sure you can cycle between units in a tile with Shift+Click on the tile.

Comment: Are you sure shift is needed? I think, and the other answers here agree with me, just a regular click is enough.

Comment: tbh im suprised this was even a question. Surely trying to click on it is the first logical step. Single clicks cycle through the avaliable units

Comment: Well, duh, obviously the question was asked because a regular click simply didn't work. That was what the question was about.

Comment: Checked now, and shift-click works for me.